# How to refactor prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I am trying to create query to analysis last 1hour behaviour of a metrics with last 1days data.  
  for example `avg of metricA[1h] / avg of merticA[1d]` metricA is gauge type.

But I want avg of each hours and then do the avg. So I created a query which is -

```
avg(increase({metricA}[1h])) by (group) /
((avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 1h )) by (group) 
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 2h )) by (group) 
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 3h )) by (group) 
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 4h )) by (group)
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 5h )) by (group)
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 6h )) by (group)
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 7h )) by (group)
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 8h )) by (group)
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 9h )) by (group) 
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 10h )) by (group)
...
...
...
...
+avg(increase({metricA}[1h] offset 24h )) by (group))/24)
```

I want avg of each hour and do the avg again instead of avg of whole data points.  It will create complex query if I want to do the analysis for 1 week or 2 week. This there any simple way to do this?